# Can't import from module despite presence of __init__.py

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure

```
project_folder/
      pyutils/
              __init__.py
              script1.py
              script2.py 
              lambdas/
                  __init__.py
                  lambda_script1.py
                  lambda_script2.py
              lambda_tests/
                  __init__.py
                  lambda_test1.py
```

Within `lambda_test1.py` I have the following attempts

```
from lambdas.lambda_script1 import * # errors saying no module named lambdas
from .lambdas.lambda_script1 import * # errors saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.lambdas'; '__main__' is not a package
from ..lambdas.lmabda_script1 import * # errors saying tried to import above top level path
```

I'm trying to run my tests from the project folder with a command like

```
python pyutils/lambda_tests/lambda_test1.py
```

But none of the options seem to work

If I run `IPython` from within the `pyutils` folder and run `from lambdas.lambda_script1 import *` it works.  Is this a python path problem?

I also tried adding an __init__.py at the project folder and it still didn't work

Comment: It is; the Python path doesn't include the current working directory automatically, only the directory where `lambda_test1.py` resides. As a result, `project_folder` isn't on the path in this case, so `pyutils`, let alone `pyutils.lambdas`, is not visible.

Comment: The simple fix, I think, would be to run `PYTHONPATH=. python pyutils/lambda_tests/lambda_test1.py`. The more proper fix would be to use a test runner that you run from `project_folder` and descends your hierarchy looking for test modules itself.

Comment: with which IDE are you working?

Comment: Working in pycharm for dev but would like to also run the command from the command line

Comment: I also tried running `python lambda_tests/lambda_test1.py` from the `pyutils` folder and still get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
project_folder/
      pyutils/
              __init__.py
              script1.py
              script2.py 
              lambdas/
                  __init__.py
                  lambda_script1.py
                  lambda_script2.py
              lambda_tests/
                  __init__.py
                  lambda_test1.py
```

Firstly, export your pythonpath to be the root of your project

`export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project_folder/py_utils`

Then you would use imports like:

`import script1`

`import script2`

`import lambdas.lambda_script1`

`import lambdas.lambda_script2`

`import lambdas_tests.lambda_test1`